# Adding meta box is only appearing in add new post not appearing in page

Tags: php, wordpress

```
    add_filter( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', 'your_prefix_meta_boxes' );
function your_prefix_meta_boxes( $meta_boxes ) {
    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'title'      => __( 'Test Meta Box', 'textdomain' ),
        'post_types' => 'post',
        'fields'     => array(
            array(
                'id'   => 'name',
                'name' => __( 'Name', 'textdomain' ),
                'type' => 'text',
            ),
            array(
                'id'      => 'gender',
                'name'    => __( 'Gender', 'textdomain' ),
                'type'    => 'radio',
                'options' => array(
                    'm' => __( 'Male', 'textdomain' ),
                    'f' => __( 'Female', 'textdomain' ),
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'id'   => 'email',
                'name' => __( 'Email', 'textdomain' ),
                'type' => 'email',
            ),
        ),
    );
    return $meta_boxes;
}
```

i had pud this code in my function.php and i am getting meta box in add new post only. i need meta box also on my page. please help me out

Comment: `'post_types' => array('post','page'),`

Comment: how to do this for specific page

Comment: https://metabox.io/docs/meta-box-include-exclude/

Answer (score 0):

You should select one of the hooks available on your pages and to add your function there. For example use page_template hook:

```
add_filter( 'page_template', 'your_prefix_meta_boxes' );
```

Comment: my template name is homepage1 
should i try this as
 `add_filter( 'homepage1', 'your_prefix_meta_boxes' );`

Comment: There is no 'homepage1' hooks. You should check what hooks are available for your post type = page. Also, use Dr.Molle advice: change 'post_types' => array('post','page')

Comment: can u please assist me something more for wordpress i m having some difficulties in it

Comment: i had mailed u sir can you pls revert me as soon as possible thnks

Comment: I've answered on your email. You can also contact me on https://wizpert.com/tarasshkodenko